# Unable to set second to last command line argument to variable

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

Regardless of the number of arguments passed to my script, I would like for the second to the last argument to always represent a specific variable in my code.

Executing the program I'd type something like this:

```
sh myprogram.sh -a arg_a -b arg_b special specific

test=("${3}")
echo $test
```

The results will show 'special'.  So using that same idea if I try this (since I won't know that number of arguments):

```
secondToLastArg=$(($#-1))
echo $secondToLastArg
```

The results will show '3'.  How do I dynamically assign the second to last argument?

Comment: Alternatively, is the 2nd-to-last argument always the first argument following a variable number of options?

Comment: @chepner I think the answer to your question is yes.  My script requires a minimum of two arguments to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a bit of math to get the number you want (`$(($#-1))`), then use indirection (`${!n}`) to get the actual argument.

```
$ set -- a b c 
$ echo $@
a b c
$ n=$(($#-1))
$ echo $n
2
$ echo ${!n}
b
$
```

Indirection (`${!n}`) tells bash to use the value of `n` as the name of the variable to use (`$2`, in this case).

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I'm not sure how or why.  I understand the ($(($#-1))), but I don't understand what is happening when you do the (${!n})

Comment: @nkon I've added a bit of explanation on the `${!n}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use $@ as array & array chopping methods:

```
echo ${@:$(($#-1)):1}
```

It means, use `1` element starting from `$(($#-1))`...

If some old versions of shells do not support `${array:start:length}` syntax but support only `${array:start}` syntax, use below hack:

```
echo ${@:$(($#-1))} | { read x y ; echo $x; } # OR
read x unused <<< `echo ${@:$(($#-1))}`
```